# How to add mapviews in listview? Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display multiple maps in my layout.

In my fragment I have a list view, in the list view item I have a mapView

```
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

In the adapter file, in my get view method I do :

```
   holder.mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                    .title("Marker in Sydney"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            holder.mapView.onResume();
        }
    });
```

But nothing shows up.

I have created a google maps API key, and added the following to my manifest.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key, not restricted"/>
```

And I have added this dependency in the griddle file:

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
```

Do you know why there is no map showing?

Comment: Any logcat error messages?

Comment: @apmartin1991 It doesn't show any errors

Answer (score 0):

Go to :
file - new - google - Google Maps Activity and Understand the things.

Add this in your xml

```
tools:context="yourpackage.YourActivityName"
```